# Galvanic cell structure and function

Tags: electrochemistry

I was thinking about galvanic cells the other afternoon and I was wondering the situation 
if a chemical engineer designs a galvanic cell using copper and zinc as electrodes, what would the structure, function and output voltage of the cell be, and how might you possibly increase the voltage?

Answer (score 1):

If by voltage, you mean electric potential, then just analyze the nernst equation.

The standard reduction potential for both half-reactions is known, so add those to get the standard cell potential. Then realize that changing the concentrations of reactions and products (hence, the reaction quotient) can change the actual cell potential (the log term in the equation).

Answer (score 0):

I think voltage is increase by increasing cocentration of zinc sulphate & Copper sulphate. Due to which we gain more sulphate ions and zinc and copper ions.